# Don't Copy Line Breaks from Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to not copy line breaks from Notepad++?  For example, I'm wring some R code for an ODBC connection and SQL query.  I want to format the query in Notepad++ like this:

```
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
FROM
  tblXyx
```

However, when I go to paste this into R, it also pastes the line breaks.  Is there a way to just copy the string without a line break included?  The actual query I'm passing to the string is pretty long so I want to format it for readability reasons in Notepad++ (instead of just having a one-liner.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could copy it to another blank file in N++ and do the command under `Edit->Blank Operations->Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL`. Not quite what you want I'm guessing but might be sufficient.

Comment: You are confirming my fears! :)